# What is the abbreviation in Spanish for the word "examples" (plural)?

Tags: traducción, plurales, abreviaturas

In Spanish, "ejemplo" is abbreviated as "ej.", but what is the abbreviation for the plural "ejemplos"?

Answer (score 6):

Quoting the *Diccionario Panhispánico de Dudas*, paragraph 5.a of [its article for abbreviations](http://buscon.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=fKODyKTfZD6s0mX7bz#5):

> 5. ***Plural***. Depende de su método de formación:
>
> a) Si la abreviatura se obtuvo por truncamiento, se añade *-s*: *págs*. por *páginas*. Se exceptúa el plural de las abreviaturas *cent*. (*centavo, centésimo*) y *cént.* (*céntimo*), que es *cts*., y no Ⓧ*cents*. ni Ⓧ*cénts*. (no debe confundirse la abreviatura *cent.* con la palabra *cent*, cuyo plural sí es *cents*). En abreviaturas formadas por una sola letra, el plural se expresa duplicando esta: *ss*. por *siguientes*, *EE. UU.* por *Estados Unidos*.

It basically says that, for abbreviations formed by chopping away the end of the word (like *ej<s>emplo</s>* -> *ej.*), to get the plural **you just add an "s"**: *ej<s>emplo</s>**s*** -> *ej**s**.*

So, directly answering your question: the abbreviation for "ejemplos" is "ejs.".